# How do I get rid of : line 1: /backup: Is a directory, error message?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, warnings

I'm trying to create a shell script which displays for a given directory the months of the last modification of its files in a sorted order.

I got it working except, I keep getting this message: script.sh: line 1: /backup: Is a directory

How do I get rid of this code?

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter directory name: "
read d
ls $d -l | awk '{print $6}' | sort
```

Comment: Some better approaches for sorting files by timestamps: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003

Comment: Also see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)